# series: $S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(1-x)^2$ is NOT uniformly convergent in $[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Question asks :

To show that the series: $S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(1-x)^2$ is NOT uniformly convergent in $[0,1]$

My work :

sum function $S(x) = 1-x \ ,$ $\forall$ $x$ $\in$ $[0,1]$

By Dini's Theorem which reads as follows as per my book *"If the sum function of a series $\sum f_{n}$ with non-negative continuous terms defined on an interval $[a,b]$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then the series is uniformly convergent on the interval"*

I find this series to be uniformly convergent. Kindly help what am i missing

Comment: The series seems to be uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ and Dini's theorem is a quick way to show this. Note that Dini's theorem also requires the sequence of functions to be monotone, which is true in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.

The maximum of $f_n(x) = (1-x)^2x^n$ can be found by setting the derivative to zero and is attained at $x = n/(2+n)$. Thus, for $x \in [0,1]$

$$0 \leqslant f_n(x) \leqslant \left(\frac{2}{2+n}\right)^2 \left(\frac{n}{2+n}\right)^n< \frac{4}{(2+n)^2} < \frac{4}{n^2}$$

Uniform convergence follows from the Weierstrass test.

Comment: The derivative on $(0,1)$ of $f_n(x)$ is $$f_n'(x)= \begin{cases} -2(1-x) & \text{if } k=0 \\ (1-x)x^{n-1}(n-x(n+2)) & \text{if } k\geq 1. \end{cases}$$ This piece-wise derivative confuses me. It turns out that there are no critical points when $k=0$. Is this problematic? After all, in the Weierstrass M-test we want to bound *all* $f_n(x)$ by some sequence $M_k$, i.e. also $f_0$.

Comment: I observe that $f_0(x)=(1-x)^2\leq 1$ for $x\in[0,1]$, so if we define $M_0=1$ and $M_n=4/n^2$ for $k\geq1$, then $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty M_n=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{n^2} <\infty,$$ so the Weierstrass theorem does indeed apply.